# S3 Bucket replication using CDK in Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to do Cross region replication using Python in CDK.
I have enabled versioning on both bucket and added policy to replicate object on destination bucket.
I Want to add "replication rule configuration" to source bucket,Have got process to do using yaml in cloudformation template.

But i want to implement same using Python.
Can anyone please suggest something for this.
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

I had a use case where I had to enable bucket replication for my bucket with multiple destination buckets.

I tried to replicate the policy defined here - https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/730#issuecomment-753692737

Here is a snippet of my code

```
    my_dest_buckets = ["bucket-1", "bucket-2"]
    s3.CfnBucket(
        self,
        "my-id",
        bucket_name="my-bucket",
        public_access_block_configuration=s3.BlockPublicAccess.BLOCK_ALL,
        bucket_encryption=s3.CfnBucket.BucketEncryptionProperty(
            server_side_encryption_configuration=[
                s3.CfnBucket.ServerSideEncryptionRuleProperty(
                    server_side_encryption_by_default=s3.CfnBucket.ServerSideEncryptionByDefaultProperty(
                        sse_algorithm="AES256"
                    )
                )
            ]
        ),
        ownership_controls=s3.CfnBucket.OwnershipControlsProperty(
            rules=[
                s3.CfnBucket.OwnershipControlsRuleProperty(
                    object_ownership="BucketOwnerPreferred"
                )
            ]
        ),
        versioning_configuration=s3.CfnBucket.VersioningConfigurationProperty(
            status="Enabled"
        ),
        replication_configuration=s3.CfnBucket.ReplicationConfigurationProperty(
            
            role=f"arn:aws:iam::{self.account}:role/my-role",
            rules=[
                # Creating rules with destination buckets other than bucket in main region
                s3.CfnBucket.ReplicationRuleProperty(
                    id=f"rule-{bucket}",
                    destination=s3.CfnBucket.ReplicationDestinationProperty(
                        bucket=f"arn:aws:s3:::{bucket}",
                    ),
                    delete_marker_replication=s3.CfnBucket.DeleteMarkerReplicationProperty(
                        status="Disabled"
                    ),
                    status="Enabled",
                    priority=count,
                    filter=s3.CfnBucket.ReplicationRuleFilterProperty(prefix="")
                    # This is an empty filter which we have added so that AWS
                    # uses latest schema (V2). By default it used old schema which allows only
                    # one destination bucket.
                )
                # For all the dest buckets
                for count, bucket in enumerate(
                    [bucket for bucket in my_dest_buckets]
                )
            ],
        ),
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is helpfull at all, but I was bound to the `Bucket` Class in Java (and not `CfnBucket`) and therefore needed a little workaround.

```
final Bucket bucket = Bucket.Builder.create(this, bucketName)
                .bucketName(bucketName)
                .publicReadAccess(live)
                ...

CfnBucket.ReplicationConfigurationProperty replicationConfigurationProperty = CfnBucket.ReplicationConfigurationProperty.builder()
                .role(replicationRole.getRoleArn())
                .rules(...)
                ...

CfnBucket cfnBucket = (CfnBucket)bucket.getNode().getDefaultChild();
cfnBucket.setReplicationConfiguration(replicationConfigurationProperty);
```

Answer (score 0):

Current cdk "S3Bucket" construct do not has direct replication method exposed. Its in AWS's feature list. But you can do with using CfnS3Bucket class.
Here you need to create the two stack one in primary region and secondary region, which will create the two buckets, one in one region and second in another region. And using Cfn constructs you can easily achieve the replication.

Sample repo for your reference: https://github.com/techcoderunner/s3-bucket-cross-region-replication-cdk

Comment: Seems like they released an update today that adds support for replication: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/releases/tag/v1.65.0

Now just need to get it working... No update on the docs site.

Comment: Nope, they have released the replication notification feature and not the actual replication implementation.

Comment: Yeah, saw that after I posted. I was able to get it working use CfnBucket and building the replication policy myself.